# How to install mongoDb connector under Windows?

Tags: ksqldb

I use KSQLdb, and I have tried to install MongoDb connector. Tutorial says to use confluent hub client or download connector jar file that include in java application.

But I want to use KSQLDB as CLI.

Default installations is:

> Download installation Or download the ZIP file and extract it into one
> of the directories that is listed on the Connect worker's plugin.path
> configuration properties. This must be done on each of the
> installations where Connect will be run.

Where to place these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connector simply needs to be on the java class path. Adding the jars to the `lib` or `ext` folder should be sufficient.